# Distance of Higgs boson before decaying in the detector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, standard-model, higgs, estimation

How much time the Higgs travels to before decays in the ATLAS detector?
Which sub-detector is used to detect it?

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that the decay lifetime in the frame of the detector is lengthened by time dilation. However the gamma factor will not be large (presumably less than 10, since a Higgs will likely not be produced with a TeV of energy or larger) so this will not be a large effect in a calculation of the Higgs' flight time.

Answer (score 3):

The width of the Higgs boson in the standard model is [about 4 MeV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#cite_note-meanlife-7) which means it  decays fast so cannot move far. From this the lifetime can be estimated which is of the order of 10^-22 seconds. Even with the speed of light , 299 792 458 m / s, ~3x10^8 M/sec one decay length is 10^-14 m. The distance traveled will be in the [picometer range.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix)

The Higgs has been discovered by studying the decay products, [the invariant mass](https://twiki.cern.ch/twiki/bin/view/CMSPublic/PhysicsResultsHIG) and the channels it decays into. [A complicated detector](https://cms.cern/detector) allows the registering of all the proton proton interaction products and analysis picks up the relevant channels .